# Connect to Stitch with React Native

Tags: react-native, mongodb-stitch

I try to initialize a Stitch default app client, but I always get an error when initializing the client.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {Stitch, AnonymousCredential} from 'mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Text>Stitch Test</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('=> App/componentDidMount');
    await this._loadClient();
  }

  _loadClient() {
    console.log('=> App/_loadClient');

    Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('tuto - nbmzq').then(client => {
      if (client.auth.isLoggedIn) {
        client.auth
          .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
          .then(user => {
            console.log('Successfully logged in as user ${user.id}');
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } else {
        console.log(client);
        console.log('Error initialize Client');     // Always fall here
      }
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

The app Id exists and I can connect it on MongoDB site.
Where Am I going wrong ?

Thanks ++ Eric

Comment: This seems to be a library specific issue, you should open a new issue on there git repo [stitch-js-sdk](https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-js-sdk/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the test after `Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient`.

It must be

```
if (client.auth.hasDeviceId) { ... }
```

instead of

```
if (client.auth.isLoggedIn) { ... }
```

which is always false because `client.auth` is made after the test.